# Automating updates of Excel-SQL connections to produce multiple dashboards

Tags: sql-server, vba, t-sql, excel

I am producing a report of a subset of our products. Each of these products has an A4 page of details presented in a dashboard using excel.

I have a number of stored procedures that excel uses to connect to my database and return the data. This data is then read by the dashboard which automatically updates.

I need to produce this dashboard for each of over 100 products and combine them into one document.

However, to update the data I currently have to go into each stored procedure connection and update the product ID manually. This is a slow task.

Is there a way to use either SQL, Excel or VBA to improve this process?

Perhaps a piece of VBA that reads a list of product IDs, updates each stored procedure in turn, saves the dashboard sheet as a PDF and repeats?

EDIT: Excel connects to the data using the stored procedures through the built in connections tool under the data tab.

Comment: The stored procedure is located in your DB, right? And how do you access it via Excel? With a macro?

Comment: @EngJon In Excel 2013: Data -> Connections. Set up the connection to SQL Server then set command type to SQL on the definition tab in the connection properties. Then just paste the SQL into the command text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the stub to use to create the SQL query from scratch using a productId:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE PRODUCT_ID = " & productId
If IsMissing(trustedConnection) Then
   sConn = "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & _
                serverInstance & ";Initial Catalog=" & database & _
                ";User ID=" & userId & ";Password=" & password & ";"
Else
   sConn = "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & _
   serverInstance & ";Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=" & _
            database & ";"
End If
'Output worksheet
Set wks = Target.Parent
With qt
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = sql
    .Name = sName
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False 'Execute SQL
End With
Set qt = wks.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=sConn, Destination:=Target)
```

**Now simply create a loop** and **create as many worksheets and these SQL queries as needed.**

Comment: To do this do I need to manually create the worksheets and save them independently?

Comment: No. You can loop through your products and include this macro above creating new worksheets for the queries automatically. After that you just need to refresh them using RefreshAll command for example

Answer (score 0):

This should help you :

```
    Sub SQL_Multi()
    '
    Dim RqSql As String, _
        RqSql = RqSql_Part1 & DicArt(i) & RqSql_Part2
        RqSql = RqSql_Part1 & DicArt(i) & RqSql_Part2
        DicArt()
    ReDim DicArt(0)
    'create or get the article list here (you can use Add_Array_To_Dico described below)
    DicArt = Add_Array_To_Dico(Array_Articles, DicArt, 1, True)


        'Add a new connection
        'Workbooks("base.xlsx").Connections.AddFromFile "D:\Documents\DEMO.odc"
'Set your query here
RqSql_Part1 = "Select * from DataBase where ID='"
RqSql_Part2 = "' and ...."

For i = LBound(DicArt) + 1 To UBound(DicArt)
        'Here is where the query is made for each ID
        RqSql = RqSql_Part1 & DicArt(i) & RqSql_Part2         '"article reference" : you can change here to place correctly the article
        With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("DEMOtest").ODBCConnection
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .CommandText = Array(RqSql)
            .CommandType = xlCmdSql
            .Connection = "ODBC;DSN=DEMO;UID=ID;PWD=PWD;APP=Microsoft Office 2013;WSID=CHA02KW;DATABASE=DEMO"
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .SavePassword = True
            .SourceConnectionFile = ""
            .SourceDataFile = ""
            .ServerCredentialsMethod = xlCredentialsMethodIntegrated
            .AlwaysUseConnectionFile = False
        End With
        'Refreshing connection
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("DEMOtest").Refresh

        'Wait long enough for refreshing to be finished (5 secs here)
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
        DoEvents
        Sheets("Dashboard").Calculate
        DoEvents

        'Export to Pdf (correct Filename)
        Sheets("Dashboard").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                    Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\All\Mains " & DicArt(i) & ".pdf", _
                    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                    OpenAfterPublish:=False

    Next i

    End Sub
```

And the custom function to get an array with unique occurences :

```
Public Function Add_Array_To_Dico(ByVal ArrayT As Variant, _
                                    ByVal DicoArray As Variant, _
                                    Optional ByVal ColIndex As Integer, _
                                    Optional ByVal HasHeaders As Boolean) _
                                    As Variant
Dim A()
ReDim A(0)
Dim IsInDico As Boolean
Dim CellCont As String
Dim StartRow As Integer

If IsMissing(HasHeaders) Then
    'consider there is no headers
    StartRow = 0
Else
    If HasHeaders Then
        StartRow = 1
    Else
        StartRow = 0
    End If
End If

For i = StartRow To UBound(ArrayT, 1)

    CellCont = ArrayT(i, ColIndex)
    IsInDico = False

    For k = LBound(DicoArray) To UBound(DicoArray)
        If CellCont <> DicoArray(k) Then

        Else
            'Matched with dictionnary
            IsInDico = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next k

    If IsInDico <> False Then
        'Already in Dictionnary
    Else
        'Add in Dictionnary
        ReDim Preserve DicoArray(UBound(DicoArray) + 1)
        DicoArray(UBound(DicoArray)) = CellCont
    End If
Next i

Add_Array_To_Dico = DicoArray
End Function
```

Comment: In this I presume DicArt is my list of product IDs? Where does this access/perform the SQL queries? i.e. is it using my existing connections or creating a new one and running the stored procedure? As you may recall I am quite new to VBA.

Comment: In fact it is the list of your IDs. You just have to **create an array** (using your initial connection maybe) and **specify the column in which the IDs are** in the 2 firsts arguments of `Add_Array_To_Dico` function. It is using your **existing connection** (if it isn't necessary to create one in code, it is not useful to do it) and the **queries are upadted in here** : `RqSql = RqSql_Part1 & DicArt(i) & RqSql_Part2` , you just have to put the respective parts of your query in Part1 and Part2 at start. Was it clear enough?